# Import .env in .env.testing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have a .env.testing file for my tests, specifically for setting a local testing database. But do I have to copy everything from .env into .env.testing, just to change one line? Can't I do some command that tells `php artisan test` that I want to load everything from .env, and then override DB_DATABASE by having only this line in .env.testing?

Comment: [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77543312/how-to-seed-to-test-database-in-laravel#comment136704489_77543312), so plenty questions with this..

Comment: You can send env variables from the command line, like `EXAMPLE=test php artisan test`, and if you then called `env('EXAMPLE')` you'd get `'test'`. I'm not sure if this would override values in `.env`, but for safety, it's considered better practice to copy `.env` to `.env.test`, and modify the line(s) required. Last thing you'd want to do is forget to change _something_ and have it act against your production env variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to seed database migrations for laravel tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350138/how-to-seed-database-migrations-for-laravel-tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just changing this line in my phpunit.xml file:

```xml
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="projectdb_testing"/>
```

It even was already there, I just had to uncomment it and change the database name.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the env system of Laravel, you can override this method in the *App/Http/Kernel.php* file

```
public function bootstrap() 
{
    app()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.test');
    parent::bootstrap(); 
}
```

I think it's a bit tricky and dangerous to change Laravel env system, but you can analyze how it's working by reading methods in the file *vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadEnvironmentVariables.php*